# How to load CollectionView cell images asynchronously?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiimage, uicollectionview

Now I have a `UICollectionView`(horizontal scrolling) which cells are contain `UIImage`. I'm using this for showing `UIImage` filters as Instagram does. But when I'm scrolling to see how images look after implementing filters - it freezes. How can I make it smooth, as in Instagram?

My code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: imageFilterCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imageFilterCell

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {             
        cell.imageView.image = self.applyFilterTo(self.image!, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.filterLabel.text = self.filtersLabels[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

where `applyFilter()` implements a filter to my Image.

Any solutions for make scrolling smooth and prevent freezing?

Comment: Instead of applying filter on image on main thread, use background thread. Once you receive filtered image, then get main queue and display image.

Comment: you can use SDWebImage here. get it from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @Surjeet so, you suggest to use as: `let img = self.applyFilterTo(self.image!, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])` and later `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { cell.imageView.image = img` }`. Yes?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35772291/2963912 with NSOperation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue()

        let op1 = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in

            let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(self.image!, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])

            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                cell.imageView.image = img1
            })
        }


queue.addOperation(op1);
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.filterLabel.text = self.filtersLabels[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want! Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe This only works, if the content will not scroll. However, you stated that your view will scroll horizontally. It does not work, because cells will be reused - and by the time the image is finished, the cell may now be reused to display another row. So, this code contains a bug.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper with all respect sir, but image is not being downloaded here so it won't take much time

Comment: How much time does you allow the function to take, until we can be sure that the potential bug will not occur in any circumstances?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper what alternative you can offer?

Comment: @JohnDoe Use `indexPath` - that is, "import" `indexPath` into the closure which executes on the main thread. Within the closure, try to obtain the cell at this indexPath. If it is `nil` this particular cell at the given index path is not visible anymore - and you don't need to setup the image. Otherwise, the cell is visible at that index path, so set the image. See also: [UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:parsedData[@"imageURL"]];

        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        if (image) {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                     cell.imageView.image = image;
                     [cell setNeedsLayout];

             });
         }
    });
```

Comment: You may add the code where you setup the tag - and explain why this code will work.

Comment: Hey @CouchDeveloper it was copied from my project